# JavaFX Text in TextFlow ignores StyleClass?

Tags: javafx

I try to use a javafx `TextFlow` to view some styled text. The following code does not do any text styling.

```
public Node createText(String t,String cls){
    Text ret = new Text(t); 
    ret.getStyleClass().add(cls);
    return ret;
}
```

When I replace `Text` with `Label` it works properly, but things like `\n` obviously do not work anymore. How can I use the `Text` class with css classes?

EDIT: As requested a short example of my default.css

```
.defaultElementAttr{
    -fx-text-fill:#48a711;  
}
```

Comment: What css are you trying to apply?

Comment: css stylesheet classes. Styling the TextFlow itself works, styling Label works too, but not the Text objects (the same code works with `Label ret = new Label(t);`)

Comment: What css styles are you trying to apply? Which actual properties are you defining rules for?

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-fx-text-fill` is a CSS property of [`Label`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) but it is not a CSS property of [`Text`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text).

If you want to change the color of a `Text` object with CSS, use the `-fx-fill` property:

```css
.defaultElementAttr {
    -fx-fill:#48a711;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Now knowing what I have to search for I found it on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape

Comment: @SalkinD JavaFX 1.3 is (long) deprecated. Use the links in the answer for more recent documentation.